# PlayN + tripleplay layout

Tags: playn

Is there an easy way to make elements in tripleplay wrap and continue below?

For example if I have this code:

```
    Group letters = new Group(AxisLayout.horizontal(), Style.HALIGN.left);
    letters.addStyles(Styles.make(Style.TEXT_WRAP.is(true)));
    root.add(letters);

    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        letters.add(new Label(""+i));
    }
```

That would show some numbers (up to, say, 30) and the rest of the numbers will dissappear off-screen, what I want to have is something like:

`01 02 03 ... 28`
`29 30 31 ... 50`

So whatever component doesn't fit on screen will be added below. I tried a few settings but wasn't able to get it

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Style.TEXT_WRAP` is only applicable to `Label`s. There is no equivalent in Tripleplay UI of Swing's `FlowLayout` which is what I think you want.

If you really just want to lay out a bunch of text, then just stick it all in one label with text wrapping enabled. But if you're trying to layout actual user interface elements in a flow, then you'll need to write your own `FlowLayout`. You can also use `TableLayout`, but that requires that you know how many columns you want in advance.

I've always found `FlowLayout` to be a weird way to lay out user interfaces, and have never had a need for it, hence I did not write one for Tripleplay UI.

Comment: another one on a similar topic, something on the line of an AbsoluteLayout (to be able to position a Group in a fixed [x,y] pair) would be feasible?

I started fiddling with the code but found that some methods in Element are protected, I don't know if that's the right way to do it, thou

Comment: An AbsoluteLayout would be very easy to implement. If I have some time this afternoon, I'll whip it up.

Comment: Better late than never: https://github.com/threerings/tripleplay/blob/master/src/main/java/tripleplay/ui/layout/AbsoluteLayout.java